# Access the .sql files with git lfs

Tags: postgresql, git, git-lfs

I have a existing repo(not a git) on my localmachine. It is using postgresql. But it has database files are stored on git-lfs. So, How do i impost that files on my loca database?

The file contains :

file name is : database.sql

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:00da579595bc41e509ea3a5198fe24607*********30a633691018e03b5c31dd
size 8998
```

I wants to set up my local data base from these files. But I have no experience with git-lfs.

Comment: What do you mean by "a repo (not a git)... that stores files in Git LFS"?

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you have Git LFS installed in your machine, you can visit [Installing Git Large File Storage](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/installing-git-large-file-storage) for a guide, then run `git lfs pull` to download the files, and finally you can apply it to your database by running `psql -U <username> -d <your_db_name> -f database.sql`.

Also note that Git LFS is an extension of `git` itself and not a standalone tool, so your repo has to be a git repository in order for you to use Git LFS.